# Show it is impossible to find a $+ve$ integer such that sum of its sq. and its cube is an integral multiple of the sq. of the next highest integer.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Based on the problem statement, we can form the equation as :-

> $x^2+x^3 = k(x+1)^2$

where $x$ and $x+1$ are positive integers and $k$ will be the integral multiple. 
One doubt that I have here is as per the statement " $k$ will be the integral multiple" , does this mean that $k$ will be a Whole number i.e. $k$ can be a positive integer, negative integer or $0$ ?

Now

> $x^2+x^3 = k(x+1)^2$ 
>  $\Rightarrow x^2(x+1) = k(x+1)^2$ 
> $\Rightarrow (x+1) [x^2-k(x+1)] = 0$

One solution will be $x =-1$ which is not a valid solution in this case.

Another solution will come from $x^2-k(x+1) =0$ which gives $x$ as :-

> $x = \frac{k}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{k(k+4)}{4}}$

How can we proceed from here in order to prove the statement? One way I was adopting was to put different integral values of $k$ and checking if we get any $x$ as a positive integer but this does not seem to be a reliable way to prove this. I am stuck at this part. Please help !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "$k$ will be the integral multiple" requires $k$ to be a whole number.  For example, if $x=-2$ then $k= -4$ while of $x=0$ then $k=0$, but neither $-2$ nor $0$ are positive integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've obtained $x = \frac{k}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{k(k+4)}{4}}$. Now let $k$ be even as otherwise x cannot be an integer. substituting $k=2p$,
$x = \frac{2p}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{2p(2p+4)}{4}} = p \pm \sqrt{p(p+2)}$

Again, p is even or p is odd.

**Case 1:** If p is odd, $p(p+2)$ is not a perfect square

(Explanation: $(2n-1)\times(2n+1) = (2n)^2-1$ is not a perfect square).

---

**Case 2:** If p is even, we can further write $\sqrt{p(p+2)} = 2\sqrt{q(q+1)}$ for some $q =\frac{p}{2}$. Again $q(q+1)$ is not a perfect square.

(Explanation: $q^2 < q(q+1) < (q+1)^2$. As q(q+1) lies between two consecutive perfect squares, it is not a perfect square).

Therefore we arrive at a contradiction to finding an integer solution in all cases

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach might be to say

$$k = \frac{x^2+x^3}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{x^2(1+x)}{(x+1)^2}= \frac{x^2}{x+1}= \frac{x^2-1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+1} =x-1+\frac{1}{x+1}$$

and, for positive integer $x$, that is strictly between $x-1$ and $x$, so not an integer

Comment: :This is smooth and quite easy.. but can you please elaborate your last line? Not able to get that part.

Comment: @Ganit do you mean $\frac{x^2-1}{x+1} = \frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x+1}=x-1$

Comment: @Ganit Remember that $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$

Comment: I meant this "and, for positive integer $x$, that is strictly between $x-1$ and $x$, so not an integer ".

Comment: @Ganit For $x > 0$ you have $0 < \frac1{x+1} < 1$